# User information in address book on iOS

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

On MacOS X I can use the method `me` in the `ABAddressBook` class to get the logged in user's record, see [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABAddressBook_Class/Reference/Reference.html). On iOS there is no similar function call (in the corresponding C interface) listed in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/ABAddressBookRef). The iOS address book does not seem to preserve this information upon synchronization.

Is there any way to identify the user under iOS or do I need to devise a proprietary mechanism for every single one of my apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid iOS does not offer a method to return the owner's contact card. I was hopeful you could get the device's phone number and then search for the same number in the address book.

The device's phone number can be found with this bit of code
`NSString *num = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"SBFormattedPhoneNumber"];`

Unfortunately getting the device's phone number is a violation of the developer agreement. Apple would reject any app that used it.

Sorry for the "no" answer. At least we both now know what doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is strange that it doesn't work. I can get the entire phone book, but not identify the owner ... Why does it work at all on the desktop, BTW? On the other hand, the method you describe would at least work for the Enterprise Program. Only for iPhones, but not iPod or iPad, but that's better than nothing.

Comment: any update on this? there are some apps on the app store that pick the `me` contact from address book